# How to add resources to two module jars in same-named folders?

Tags: java, jar, java-platform-module-system

Assuming we have two jar files with two different modules. Both jar-files include some resources (lets say png-files) in a folder called `images` in their jar. When I now try to start a module in java I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package images in both module A and module B
```

Although my `images` folder is not meant to be a package but is just a folder containing resources. So how can I get two modules with an `images`-folder onto my module-path?